# Blender beginner with Bone Problem

Tags: bones, pose-mode

I recently created an armor with various bones. But when I go to connect them it starts to rotate in all directions for no reason. I have constrained the bone of the lower arm with the inverse kinematics command ... When I go to select the second bone after the objective pole it starts to rotate, even if I change the angle pole it doesn't fix.

How do I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ok, i'm very stupid ... i didn't add the chain length. For all those who don't understand I mean the length that the movement has to influence: this right here
[image]